# How to install specific version of maven in mac using brew command

Tags: macos, maven, homebrew

I want to install specific version (3.0.5) of maven in my using brew command. I tried the following command which is failed with **Error: No available formula with the name "3.0.5"**

```
brew install maven 3.0.5
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
brew install https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions/master/maven30.rb
```

it will then use a different Homebrew's formular which will give you the maven 3.0.5 instead

**I tried this last on my Mac and it works installing the 3.0.5!**

If none works and you can use similar version try the below:

```
brew install maven30
```

What OS do you have? On OS X 10.9 you should use brew install maven30 since maven 3.1.1 seems to be buggy.

By the way:

Using Homebrew:

```
you@host:~$ brew install maven will install Maven 3.3.1 (3/24/15)
you@host:~$ brew install maven30 will install Maven 3.0 which should be
```

better

If you got a 404 error, try doing a brew update just before.

If always nothing, try to recover the installation:

```
cd ~/Documents
mkdir BrewRecovery
cd BrewRecovery
curl -OL https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ilovezfs/21a741a78927a17b9ad1/raw/fef5866ccd51f07a9635fcb1096e8df0479af01b/Brewfile-deanchester.brewfile
md5 Brewfile-deanchester.brewfile
```

Comment: I have OS X EI Capitan (10.11.3). I tried all of the above, none of them work. Error: No available formula with the name "maven30", 400 bad request for github link

Comment: Ok, sorry i tried them all and all of them worked for me :(

Comment: In the past all of them, now i just tried this one: brew install maven30

Comment: LM-SFA-11002825:~ dvayyala$ brew install maven30
Error: No available formula with the name "maven30"
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
LM-SFA-11002825:~ dvayyala$ brew install maven30
Error: No available formula with the name "maven30"
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
Error: No formulae found in taps.

Comment: Sounds so strange to me... Did you usually use brew to install software? have you something like a proxy activated?

Comment: No, I installed so many other softwares. I can even install maven with brew install maven which is installing 3.3.x which I don't want

Comment: The only thing can give an explanation is that maybe I'm caching something on my mac, and that's the reason its working for me.. Sorry i did not help you.. by the way you got your manual installation now..

Comment: 'brew search maven' shows that it now only provides 3.1 and 3.2 as versions. My particular issue is installing Maven 2 alongside (not instead of) Maven 3, and this appears to be rather difficult.

Comment: it looks like this wont work any more.  No available formula with the name "maven30"

Answer (score 51):

```
brew search maven
```

lists all maven versions as below

maven                                             maven-completion                                  maven-shell                                       maven@3.0                                         maven@3.1                                         maven@3.2 ✔                                       maven@3.3

```
brew install maven@3.0
```

Installs maven 3.0.5 on my mac.

Comment: This is the actually correct answer to this question these days!

Comment: Yes indeed this is the correct answer and the simplest.

Comment: Seems that this version is not available anymore:


`⇒ brew search maven ==> Formulae maven ✔ maven-completion maven-shell maven@3.2 maven@3.3 maven@3.5`

Comment: Same for me, I can't see maven@3.0 in my results when I run "brew search maven"

Comment: Works perfectly for the use case asked

Comment: Shows unversioned maven in Homebrew 4.1.21

Answer (score 1):

If you run `brew install maven`, the latest stable version would be installed.

If you want to install the previous versions you can run
`brew install maven@versionNumber` where versionNumber is your desired version.

Not all versions are available here in,

Also you may try hitting the website with the required version and download the file its available

https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/apache-maven/3.6.1/.

where you may substitute 3.6.1 with the version you want to run.

Answer (score 1):

### MacOS manual installation

1. Goto https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/apache-maven/3.6.3/
2. Change the version to your desired version at the end of the URL
3. Download `apache-maven-<version>-bin.tar.gz`
4. Open your terminal and run `tar xzvf Downloads/apache-maven-<version>-bin.tar.gz`
5. Add maven to your path in your `~/.zshrc` or `~/.bash_profile`

   ```bash
   export MAVEN_HOME=~/apache-maven-3.6.3
   export PATH=$PATH:$MAVEN_HOME/bin
   ```
6. Restart your terminal or load the terminal with the latest shell profile

   ```bash
   source ~/.zshenv
   source ~/.bash_profile
   ```
7. Confirm your installation with `mvn -version`

---

> PS: If you see the messge `“libjansi.jnilib” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified.` select `Move to bin`. This message might appear when running `mvn -version` for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

In general,

brew is unable to install any specific version such as 3.8.1
as it only gives few versions as the available options.

The only way then to install would be do it [manually](https://maven.apache.org/install.html).

Also don't forget to update Path variable in your mac.